# Logical Formalization of: "Children don't eat pasta with spinach or mushrooms on it"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I want to formalize the following sentence in predicate logic:

> If a children has spinach or mushrooms on its pasta then it will not
>   eat its pasta.

The headline contains a shorter version. I have four solutions where l like your opinion or recommendation on:

\begin{align}
\forall x \forall y \, &((IsChildren(x) \land IsPasta(y) \land {} \\
&\land (hasIngridient(y,Spinach) \lor hasIngridient(y,Mushroom)) \rightarrow \neg Eatspasta(x,y) )
\end{align}

1. Modification: Could I omit $IsChildren(x)\land IsPasta(y)$ though naming $x$ in child and $y$ in pasta? For example:
   \begin{align}
   \forall child \forall pasta \, &((hasIngridient(pasta,Spinach) \lor hasIngridient(pasta,Mushroom)) \\
   &\rightarrow \neg EatsPasta(child,pasta) )
   \end{align}

Q1.1 Are variables allowed with more then one letter?

Q1.2 I think the name of a variable (is child or $x$) does not matter for its interpretation. So after the first modification child could be anything from my discourse universe.

2. Modification: Could I omit $\forall y$ by changing the formalization as follows:
   \begin{align}
   \forall x \, &(isChilrden(x) \land (hasIngridientSpinachOnPasta(x) \lor hasIngridientMushroomOnPasta(x)) \\
   &\rightarrow \neg EatsPasta(x) )
   \end{align}
3. Modification: Could I omit $\forall y$ by changing the formalization as follows:
   \begin{align}
   \forall x \, &(isChilrden(x) \land (hasIngridientSpinach(Pasta) \lor hasIngridientMushroomOnPasta(Pasta)) \\ 
   &\rightarrow \neg EatsPasta(x,Pasta) )
   \end{align}
4. Modification: Could I say instead there exist no chilrden that eats pasta with Spinat und Mushrooms:
   $$\neg \exists x \forall y x(isChilrden(x) \land (Pasta(y,Spinach) \lor Pasta(y,Mushroom)) \rightarrow EatsPasta(x,y) )$$

Main question: which one are incorrect and why?

Answer (score 0):

> Q1.1 Are variables allowed with more then one letter?

It's unusual in maths; usually a one-letter symbol with descriptive index is preferred, such as $n_\mathrm{mushrooms}$. But IMO multi-character names are fine, as are multi-character functions ($\sin$, $\log$...). But LaTeX won't typeset these properly if you just write out the letters like that; notice the bad [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) in your post. You should instead wrap such names in a suitable `\math??{.}` styling. Options are:

- $Spinach$ (`$Spinach$`) (bad!)
- $\mathit{Spinach}$ (`$\mathit{Spinach}$`)
- $\mathrm{Spinach}$ (`$\mathrm{Spinach}$`)
- $\mathbf{Spinach}$ (`$\mathbf{Spinach}$`)
- $\mathsf{Spinach}$ (`$\mathsf{Spinach}$`)
- $\mathtt{Spinach}$ (`$\mathtt{Spinach}$`)

I would recommend `\mathit` for multi-character *variables*, `\mathrm` for constants and standard functions, and `\mathsf` or `\mathtt` for special situations (like when you're paraphrasing computer code).

> Q1.2 I think the name of a variable (is child or x) does not matter for its interpretation

Correct. This is what's in CS called [$\alpha$-conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B1-conversion): any variable that's quantified over with $\forall$ or $\exists$ can be renamed.

Your modifications 2 and 3 don't quite express the original thing, because you don't quantify over the pasta anymore. Basically this means that the pasta is a “global constant”, you only ever consider one. This is often done in maths/science for simplification, but logic-wise it does make a difference.

Modification 4 just turns around the quantors. This can always be done in classical logic:
$$
  (\forall x. \neg P(x)) \leftrightarrow \neg(\exists x. P(x))
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply. Regarding Modification 2 and 3: do you think in consideration of the original sentence that it is necessary to quantify over pasta?